# Gradle assembly debug failing for Gearvr

Tags: mobile, sdk, android-ndk, android-gradle-plugin, oculus

I am trying to run an gearVR application from android studio. I am seeing the following [error](https://gist.github.com/Akhilj786/256098e3bdf5f4629a13fc6a4d523356) from framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Missed few configuration/settings.
Follow this https://github.com/Samsung/GearVRf/releases/tag/v3.0.1 to upgrade the version.